How to find use of GPL symbols in kernel module?
I am working on a fairly complex closed source kernel module and I am unable to compile it using some toolchains without setting the license to GPL.
modpost complains about the use of a specific GPL symbol lockdep_init_map_type(). Grepping the modules source shows no hits and I am unable to determine how this symbol is used. (I don't even know what it is usually used for.)

I can compile the module as "Proprietary" for Linux v6.1.42
I can compile the module as "GPL" for Linux v6.1.87
I can NOT compile the module as "Proprietary" for Linux v6.1.87

The corresponding toolchain for Linux v6.1.42 is a Buildroot toolchain. The one for the Linux v6.1.87 is a crosstools-ng one.
How can I find out why the same source does not build for both kernel versions as "Proprietary"?
How can I tell which symbols changes from not GPL to GPL between two kernel versions?
If I do not use a GPL symbol directly why does modpost complain?

note:
lockdep_init_map_type is declared EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL in both kernel versions.

I corrected the spelling of "proprietary". If your problem was that you misspelled this symbol, perhaps simply delete this question.

Thanks, the misspelling appears only in the stack overflow question not the source.

The Linux kernel project does not want to have the proprietary code. In times it's getting tougher and tougher to be closed source in regard to the Linux Kernel Project. Read this: https://lwn.net/Kernel/Index/#Copyright_issues (the recent one is https://lwn.net/Articles/939842/). Hope this answers your question.

So, if you need a proprietary one, you may do it for yourself w.o. rights to distribute, or switch to another (from legal perspective) OS, such as FreeBSD.

What is most important to me is figuring out how the symbol is pulled in. And why there is a difference between the two working/not working builds.

In my case the culprit was sema_init.
sema_init->lockdep_init_map->lockdep_init_map_type
since all these functions are declares static inline in a header there is no way to use semaphores without GPL.
I found this by grepping the output .o files and disassembling the one that contained a hit for lockdep_init_map_type.
Then I found the offending function and started to comment out sections of the source until I found the offending source line. There is probably a better way to do this... but I do not know it.
Knowing which line causes the problem does not explain why it is compiling under some conditions though. From the info gathered above I would expect any code using sema_init to require GPL.
What happened is that for the versions that compile the CONFIG is such that semaphores are implemented differently and lockdep_init_map is declared as a macro that does nothing. i.e. does not call lockdep_init_map_type...
I found this out by getting the compile command from the objectfile.o.cmd file and running gcc with -E (preprocess only) and inspecting the output.
turns out there is a define, CONFIG_LOCKDEP, that turns on the use of lockdep_init_map_type under certain configuration.
